# How to simply generate unique key only for current session?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, session-timeout

Is there any way to generate only one unique key and save it to cookie only for current session until the browser close?

```
$key = uniqid(mt_rand());
```

Comment: For what purposes you want to use it because PHP does this already for you in session_name.

Comment: when i reload browser `$key` generate different keys..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

session_id itself is the unique id, try

```
$key = session_id();
```